# Node.js server can't reached error in aws ec2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, sails.js

Refereed so many issues related to this thread but nothing is helped me

I have an Ubuntu server running in `aws-ec2` server and a node project is running in port `1337`

But when i try to access my project with `<public-ip>:<port>` i got page can't be reached error.

**Note**

I have added `http` rule in security group settings with value is `0.0.0.0/0` and i tested it with nginx installation.
It works fine nginx default page is loaded without any issue but the node app is not loading

Comment: Did you also open the port 1337 in security group?

Comment: How to open it??

Comment: You mean custom TCP rule

Comment: Solved it but i got cors issue

Comment: But its a sails.js application and i have already  enables cors

Comment: Is your web application runs in the same domain and port?

Comment: Domain means? currently the public ip is not pointed to any domains

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149283/discussion-between-ashan-and-jabaa).

Answer (score 3):

Add a **Custom TCP** rule opening the port 1337 to allow inbound access in addition to **http** rule in the security group.